# Why does get_the_time('F j') return November 30 for all posts?

Tags: query, blog

Okay, so I'm making the blog page for my WordPress site.  My front page is displayed as static, so my blog posts are on another page called "Journal."  I want to display the posts in an archive-like fashion.  I'm trying to achieve the following:

[image]

I researched how to do this, and I found a way; however, it displays the dates for all the posts as "November 30."

[image]

This is the code I'm using:

```
                <?php
                // Get years that have posts
                $years = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS year FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY year ASC" );

                //  For each year, do the following
                foreach ( $years as $year ) {

                    // Get all posts for the year
                    $posts_this_year = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID, post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' AND YEAR(post_date) = '" . $year->year . "'" );

                    // Display the year as a header
                    echo '<h1>' . $year->year . '</h1>';

                    // Start an unorder list
                    echo '<ul class="posts-in-year">';

                    // For each post for that year, do the following
                    foreach ( $posts_this_year as $post ) {
                        // Display the title as a hyperlinked list item
                        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . $post->post_title . '</a>' . ' ' . '&mdash;' . ' ' .  get_the_time('F j') . '</li>';
                    }

                    // End the unordered list
                    echo '</ul>';
                }
                ?>
```

Basically, I'm trying to get the time from each post and display its month and day (F j)

Comment: It's because you're not using it in a WordPress loop

Comment: @MannyFleurmond I put it in a loop, and it just outputs the same thing twice.

Comment: You aren't putting it in a `WP_Query loop`.  `get_the_time` is only designed to work either in the main WordPress loop or a custom loop using `WP_Query`

Comment: @MannyFleurmond Oh, okay.  What would I query? `$years`?  I'm unfamiliar with `$wpdb`.

Comment: Just posted an answer with the proper usage of `get_the_time`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `get_the_time` is only designed to work either in the main WordPress loop or a custom loop using `WP_Query`, so the way you are using it won't work correctly.  The following is the right way to use it, using a custom `WP_Query` loop:

```
<?php
// Get years that have posts
$years = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(post_date) AS year FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY year ASC;" );

//  For each year, do the following
foreach ( $years as $year ) {    
    // Get all posts for the year.  Using WP_Query instead of custom mySQL
    $posts_this_year = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'year' => $year->year
    ) );    

    // Display the year as a header
    echo '<h1>' . $year->year . '</h1>';

    // Start an unorder list
    echo '<ul class="posts-in-year">';

    // As long as you have posts for that year, do the following.  Using the Loop.  get_the_date now works
    while ( $posts_this_year->have_posts() ) {
        //Makes current post available to template tag functions like get_the_time
        $posts_this_year->the_post(); 
        // Display the title as a hyperlinked list item
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>' . ' ' . '&mdash;' . ' ' .  get_the_time('F j') . '</li>';
    }

    //Reset post data.  Important to do this so not to mess with main loop
    wp_reset_postdata();

    // End the unordered list
    echo '</ul>';
}

?>
```

The Loop, which I was referring to earlier, is  when you use `WP_Query` to iterate through the posts for you.  When you do it that way, functions like `get_the_time` work properly because they can pull the info for the current post in the loop.  For more information, read The codex data on [`WP_Query` and multiple loops](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Multiple_Loops)

Comment: Edited with some info to how and why this works.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(post_date) AS year FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY year ASC;` is 40 times faster on my machine. Also, a date query with all the years might save more queries.

Comment: @toscho was just reusing his code.  Thanks for the catch.